# Однократная сборка общих модулей для нескольких проектов

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

Есть несколько проектов c++/qt - каталог apps. Проекты использую те или иные модули - каталог modules. Проекты объединены шаблоном subdirs.

```
[apps]          - N проектов
[modules]       - N модулей, где модуль - это каталог с .pri файлом
myprojects.pro  - subdirs
-structure.pri  - задаёт путь к app и modules
-build.pri      - задаёт путь к bin каталогу для всех бинарников
```

Можно ли настроить проекты так, чтобы файлы из каталога [modules] собирались один раз для всех проектов, в которых они используются?

Сейчас в результате сборки получается набор каталогов по количеству проектов. В каждом - своя копия .o - файлов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С такой структурой проектов, как у вас - нельзя. Чтобы модуль собирался один раз, он должен быть статической библиотекой. Для этого все ваши .pri-модули сделайте отдельными проектами (их также можно подключать в subdirs) и добавьте туда следующую конфигурацию:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
```

В основной проект добавьте статическую компоновку с этим модулем:

```
LIBS += -L[путь к библиотеке] -l[имя библиотеки]
```

Обратите внимание, что в начало имени файла библиотеки компилятор добавляет префикс `lib`. В строке подключения библиотеки этот префикс нужно выбросить.